# Is this mysql query right or wrong?

Tags: java, mysql, join

```
   "select full_name from user u join user_contact_info ui on ui.user_id=u.user_id,
   ui.user_contact_state, ui.user_contact_city_town, ui.user_contact_country where 
   u.full_name like '"+keyWord+"%'" + "and u.user_id = "+id;
```

from my user u table I want the fullname and from my user_contact_info table ui i want the
state city and country.

Am i writing the join query to get all the values based on the id. I want to know whether am 
writing the query correctly or not. If wrong How should i write it. Please help me writing join query.

Also in result set how to get the values if i am using a single table 
I will write my rs as

```
  if(rs.next()){
  User user = new User();
  user.setFullname(rs.get(full_name);
  }
```

In case of using a second join table how to get and set the values in my object.

Comment: Have you tested the query? Does it give you the correct answer? With all software development you need to know what you expect your code to do and be able to test it. You generally can't tell just by looking at a piece of code if it is correct or not. Test cases are essential.

Comment: @Cam i tested it its not yielding the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select u.full_name, ui.user_contact_state, ui.user_contact_city_town, ui.user_contact_country 
from user u 
left outer join user_contact_info ui on ui.user_id=u.user_id 
where u.full_name like '"+keyWord+"%'" + "and u.user_id = "+id
```

Note: you probably do not need the `full_name` comparison in your WHERE clause, as I assume user_id is unique per user, so will get you the correct record.

The query below should be all you need:

```
"select u.full_name, ui.user_contact_state, ui.user_contact_city_town, ui.user_contact_country 
from user u 
left outer join user_contact_info ui on ui.user_id=u.user_id 
where u.user_id = "+id
```

Comment: I want the fullname as per the keyword. when i search using the keyword. so oly i added full_name like keyword